# Using plain javascript/jquery to save user sorted table order and save it in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am facing an issue while using Jquery and PHP in same files as to sort the table. I searched quite a while found that a solution has been presented using JQuery UI to save the sorted list and then send it to php form using ajax, however due to project constraints I can't include JQuery UI as we are already using Bootstrap. So I am limited to use vanilla javascript or jquery 1.7 . Here is a snippet of my code

```
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a class="icon-pencil icon-gray" href="unit_custom_fields.php?szAction=Edit&szUnitCustomFieldId=' . $pUnitCustomField->m_uId . '" title="Edit"></a></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $pUnitCustomField->m_szFieldPlaceholder . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $pUnitCustomField->m_szFieldDescription . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . ($pUnitCustomField->m_bShowInUnitList == 1 ? "yes" : "no") . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . ($pUnitCustomField->m_bIsPasswordField == 1 ? "yes" : "no") . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a class="icon-arrow-down moveDown"  href="javascript:;" onclick="sortUnitCustomFields()"></a><a class="icon-arrow-up moveUp" href="javascript:;" onclick="sortUnitCustomFields()"></a>';
        echo '</tr>';
```

Here is how the user can sort the table with up and down arrows using Jquery

```
        global $g_szUnitCustomFieldPriority;

    $g_szUnitCustomFieldPriority .= <<< END
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function sortUnitCustomFields() {
        $('.moveUp').live('click', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var prev = row.prev();
            if (prev.length == 1) {
                    row.detach();
                    prev.before(row);
            }

        });

        $('.moveDown').live('click', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var next = row.next('tr');
            if (next.length == 1) {
                row.detach();
                next.after(row);
            } 

        });
      }
      </script>
END;
```

In order to save changes to the form I am using POST methods when the save button is clicked like

```
if ($szAction == 'Save') {
   $pUnitCustomField->m_szFieldPlaceholder = $_POST['szFieldPlaceholder'];
}
```

So How can I save the sort order in the m_szFieldPlaceholder without using Jquery UI.

Comment: Legacy jQuery UI v1.11.4 will work with jQuery v1.7. So you could make use of that in BootStrap.

Comment: Note in your code: `.live()` has been deprecated. See this note from the jQuery api: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.` from [the jQuery api docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Basically, if you change `.live` to `.on` everything should continue working the same and you will be compliant. (Note: solve your problem first, then consider this change last - once all else is working.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is inside the form tag change this line and pass the placeholder through a hidden form input like:

```
echo '<td>' . $pUnitCustomField->m_szFieldPlaceholder . '<input type="hidden" name="szFieldPlaceholder[]" value="'.$pUnitCustomField->m_uId.'" /></td>';
```

Then retrieve the data like:

```
if ($szAction == 'Save') {
       $flip = array_flip($_POST['szFieldPlaceholder']);
       $order = $flip[$pUnitCustomField->m_uId];
       $pUnitCustomField->m_szFieldPlaceholder = $order;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI should not be needed to save your information back to the PHP-side database.

What you need to do is to:

1. get an updated ordering of the table rows and store in an array or some such; then
2. send that order back to the PHP side via ajax. (Ajax is the "system" by which javascript communicates with php).
3. On the PHP side, you receive the table order and
4. store that order into a table. THEN
5. you modify your normal page build to retrieve the row order data from teh database (need to also handle if it does not exist - i.e. user has not re-ordered the rows), and
6. then re-order the table into that order before handing control over to the user.

jQueryUI would not be needed for that process (nor can I imagine how it could be used to do the front-end/back-end communications. That is not what jQueryUI is for.)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use jQuery UI Sortable, you can do so with jQuery v1.7. Simply use jQuery UI 1.11.4. Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("table tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    handle: ".sort-handle"
  });

  $("table .ui-icon-pencil").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).parents("tr").data("id");
    var url = "unit_custom_fields.php?szAction=Edit&szUnitCustomFieldId=" + id;
    console.log("Edit: " + url);
    //window.location.href = url;
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    var data = $("table tbody").sortable("serialize");
    console.log("Sort Data: " + data);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr id="m_uId-1" data-id="1">
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
    </td>
    <td>FieldPlaceHolder 1</td>
    <td>ShowInUnitList 1</td>
    <td>IsPasswordField 1</td>
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical sort-handle"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="m_uId-2" data-id="2">
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
    </td>
    <td>FieldPlaceHolder 2</td>
    <td>ShowInUnitList 2</td>
    <td>IsPasswordField 2</td>
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical sort-handle"></span>
  </tr>
  <tr id="m_uId-3" data-id="3">
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
    </td>
    <td>FieldPlaceHolder 3</td>
    <td>ShowInUnitList 3</td>
    <td>IsPasswordField 3</td>
    <td>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical sort-handle"></span>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Save</button>
```

Now you can make use of Sortable and it's methods, like `"serialize"` and `"toArray"` as you desire.

Hope that helps.